# Controlling the shape of metal

Tags: computational-chemistry, metal

Is there a way to control the shape of metal? Suppose I have a fast melting metal, is there a way to make it take a specific shape? Of course I don't mean to like put it in a template to take the shape of a template, but rather to control the shape using a computer or something. Is something like this possible or done? If not possible, then why?

Answer (score 4):

Molten or solid at the end?  It can be shaped in an induction field (liquid)  or dimagnetically levitated (liquid to solid).  Magnetoforming, hydroforming.  Spin molten into into an oblate ellipsoid (solid).

http://www.capturedlightning.com/frames/shrinkergallery.html 
Z-pinch and such.

Munroe effect for jets and planes (angle charges), and self-forging munitions.